# Why do I need to have this pointer as an attribute?

Tags: c++

I want to create a class of static array of integers but I don't know why this attribute (the pointer to integer objects "int *mem") is needed to declare it and which its functionallity is in this context. I'm not sure for example if it's needed to get access to array positions or knowing the position of an element of the array...

Here's my piece of code:

```
#ifndef STATICARRAY_H
#define STATICARRAY_H

class Staticarray {
int size;
int *mem;
};
#endif
/* STATICARRAY_H */
```

Comment: Why not use `std::vector``?

Comment: If it is a static array you don't need a pointer. I detect an [X-Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you trying to do with this object?

Comment: Are you asking how to create an array? Or something else? Which C++ book are you using?

Answer (score 0):

1. `int *mem;` is the pointer to the contents of `Staticarray`
2. You should allocate enough memory to hold the contents e.g. `mem = new int[size];`
3. remember to delete mem at the destructor of Staticarray e.g. `delete[] mem;`
4. To access the *ith* element of a `Staticarray` object called `arr` you would use `arr.mem[i];`

Comment: Bad advice. We don't do manual memory management; haven't since 1998.

Comment: I don't intend to offer advice but answer the specific question. And by the way, lot's of people including me *have* to do manual memory allocation in C++ even today. Granted, it's never plan A!